# Visual Studio diagnostics configuration error in event hub set up

Tags: visual-studio, azure, etw, azure-eventhub, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to set up streaming from an Azure VM scale set to an event hub via Diagnostics configuration.

I have my public config which includes the SinksConfig as follows (I have omitted the rest of the config for the sake of brevity):

```
{
 "WadCfg": {
     "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {

     *** config for performance counters and ETW ***

       "SinksConfig": {
            "Sink": [
             {
               "name": "eventhub",
               "EventHub": {
               "Url": "sb://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/mycompanyapplication",
               "SharedAccessKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     },
    "StorageAccount": "<storageaccount>"
}
```

and the private config:

```
{
   "storageAccountName": "<storageaccountname>",
   "storageAccountKey": "<storageaccountkey>",
   "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net",
   "EventHub": {
         "Url": "sb://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/mycompanyapplication",
         "SharedAccessKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
         "SharedAccessKey": "<sharedaccesskey>"
   }
}
```

However, nothing is being received by the event hub. I can see in the storage account logs that the Diagnostics extension is running:

[image]

but in the substatus there are many errors around the SAS key and the event hub:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I check back in the Visual Studio Diagnostics configuration on the Scale set I see this error:

[image]

I have checked the naming convention on the SharedAccessKeyName (which is the default provided when the event hub was set up) know that the SAS key works as I wrote a console app to send messages to the same event hub with the same credentials and it worked fine.

So there is obviously a problem with the authentication to the event hub as it can't read the access key from the config file. However, I can't see any other way of providing it.

Am I missing something obvious here in my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was quite simple, I had grabbed the URL from the connection string in the portal which was

```
sb://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/mycompanyapplication
```

when it should have been

```
https://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/mycompanyapplication
```

Now the data is flowing freely into the event hub.

However, the diagnostics config in VS still shows the warning about not being able to read the SAS key, which now looks like a "red herring" that ended up costing me a lot of time :(